# Is there any package for case-control matching (individual 1:N matching) in R (NOT propensity score matching)?

Tags: r

I would like to do individual matching (1:N) for case-control study in R.

Matching or MatchIt package is for propensity score matching which is not appropriate for case-control matching.

On the other hand, I could not find the proper package for individual 1:N matching based on case-control study design.

Is there any package for doing it or other process of codes?

Thanks advance.

Comment: Should be a simple matter to run with sapply or mapply using `sample`. So probably not something anyone thought would need a package. Post a reproducible example to fill in the missing particulars for demonstration needs.

Comment: Additional warning: Asking for a package is verboten on SO (and is a specific cause for closure) but asking how to do a particular task is encouraged.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Matching` or `MatchIt` to match on values other than the propensity score.

In `Matching`, enter the variable you wish to nearest-neighbor match on into the `X` argument in `Match()`. If you want to do a Mahalanobis distance match using multiple variables you can just enter multiple variables into `X`. If you want to exact match on some variables, you can do that by entering those variables into the `exact` argument. Make sure you set `M` to be whatever you want your matching ratio to be (i.e., the n in 1:n).

In `MatchIt`, enter the variable you wish to match on into the `distance` argument in `matchit()`. If you want to exact match on some variables, you can do that by entering those variables into the `exact` argument. Make sure you set `ratio` to be whatever you want your matching ratio to be.

Finally, `designmatch` is a great package for matching. Its interface is a little complicated but highly flexible, and it uses optimization to find the best matches. It makes it easy to match on many variables at the same time without computing a summary score to match on.

Answer (score 0):

i think matchit cant used for case control study design which is a package for cohort study. i'm not sure but it matches treated and untreated individuals