# Matching controls to cases using multiple conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to match 2 `controls` for every `case` with two conditions:

1. the `age` difference should between ±2;
2. the `income` difference should between ±2.

If there are more than 2 `controls` for a case, I just need select 2 `controls` randomly.
There is an example:

## EXAMPLE

### DATA

```
dat = structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 
                     777, 888, 999, 1000), 
              age = c(10, 20, 44, 11, 12, 11, 8, 12,  11, 22, 21, 18, 21, 18), 
              income = c(35, 72, 11, 35, 37, 36, 33,  70, 34, 74, 70, 44, 76, 70), 
              group = c("case", "case", "case", "case", "control", "control", 
                        "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
                        "control", "control", "control")), 
         row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
> dat
# A tibble: 14 x 4
      id   age income group  
   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>  
 1     1    10     35 case   
 2     2    20     72 case   
 3     3    44     11 case   
 4     4    11     35 case   
 5   111    12     37 control
 6   222    11     36 control
 7   333     8     33 control
 8   444    12     70 control
 9   555    11     34 control
10   666    22     74 control
11   777    21     70 control
12   888    18     44 control
13   999    21     76 control
14  1000    18     70 control
```

### EXPECT OUTCOME

For `id = 1`, the matched controls as below, and I just need select 2 `controls` randomly in the table below.

| id | age | income | group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 12 | 37 | control |
| 222 | 11 | 36 | control |
| 333 | 8 | 33 | control |
| 555 | 11 | 34 | control |

For `id = 2`,the matched controls as below, and I just need select 2 `controls` randomly in the table below.

| id | age | income | group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 666 | 22 | 74 | control |
| 777 | 21 | 70 | control |
| 1000 | 18 | 70 | control |

For `id = 3`,there is no matched `controls` in `dat`.

For `id = 4`, the matched controls as below, and I just need select 2 `controls` randomly in the table below.

> One thing to note here is that we can find that the controls for `id = 1` and `id = 4` have overlapping parts. I don't want two `cases` to share a `control`, what I need is that if `id = 1` chooses `id = 111` and `id = 222` as `control`, then `id = 4` can only choose `id = 555` as `control`, and if `id = 1` chooses `id = 111` and `id = 333` as control, then `id = 4` can only choose `id = 222` and `id = 555` as controls.

| id | age | income | group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 12 | 37 | control |
| 222 | 11 | 36 | control |
| 555 | 11 | 34 | control |

The final output maybe like this(the `id` in `control` group is randomly selected from the `id` that meets the conditions):

| id | age | income | group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 35 | case |
| 2 | 20 | 72 | case |
| 3 | 44 | 11 | case |
| 4 | 11 | 35 | case |
| 111 | 12 | 37 | control |
| 222 | 11 | 36 | control |
| 333 | 8 | 33 | control |
| 555 | 11 | 34 | control |
| 777 | 21 | 70 | control |
| 1000 | 18 | 70 | control |

### NOTE

I've looked up some websites, but they don't meet my needs. I don't know how to implement my requirements using R code.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

### Reference:

1.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56026700/is-there-any-package-for-case-control-matching-individual-1n-matching-in-r-n

2.[Case control matching in R (or spss), based on age, sex and ethnicity?](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Case-control-matching-in-R-or-spss-based-on-age-sex-and-ethnicity)

3.[Matching case-controls in R using the ccoptimalmatch package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ccoptimalmatch/vignettes/ccoptimalmatching_vignette.html)

4.[Exact Matching in R](https://nhsrcommunity.com/blog/exact-matching-in-r/)

Comment: @AnilGoyal, I update `dat`. Yes, I want random selection in final output also.

Comment: I am studying the answers below one by one.

Comment: @ AnilGoyal, In my real situation, the `control` choices overlap, so I've updated the example.

Comment: Overlap part I understand, but why 6 controls in output? Do you mean 2 per I'd?

Comment: Because there is no matched  `control` for `id = 4`.

Comment: please see edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per modified requirement, I propose the following `for loop`

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)

dat %>%
  split(.$group) %>%
  list2env(envir = .GlobalEnv)
#> <environment: R_GlobalEnv>

control$FILTER <- FALSE
control
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>       id   age income group   FILTER
#>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>   <lgl> 
#>  1   111    12     37 control FALSE 
#>  2   222    11     36 control FALSE 
#>  3   333     8     33 control FALSE 
#>  4   444    12     70 control FALSE 
#>  5   555    11     34 control FALSE 
#>  6   666    22     74 control FALSE 
#>  7   777    21     70 control FALSE 
#>  8   888    18     44 control FALSE 
#>  9   999    21     76 control FALSE 
#> 10  1000    18     70 control FALSE

set.seed(123)

for(i in seq_len(nrow(case))){
  x <- which(between(control$age, case$age[i] -2, case$age[i] +2) & 
               between(control$income, case$income[i] -2, case$income[i] + 2) & 
               !control$FILTER)
  control$FILTER[sample(x, min(2, length(x)))] <- TRUE
}

control
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>       id   age income group   FILTER
#>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>   <lgl> 
#>  1   111    12     37 control TRUE  
#>  2   222    11     36 control TRUE  
#>  3   333     8     33 control TRUE  
#>  4   444    12     70 control FALSE 
#>  5   555    11     34 control TRUE  
#>  6   666    22     74 control FALSE 
#>  7   777    21     70 control TRUE  
#>  8   888    18     44 control FALSE 
#>  9   999    21     76 control FALSE 
#> 10  1000    18     70 control TRUE

bind_rows(case, control) %>% filter(FILTER | is.na(FILTER)) %>% select(-FILTER)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>       id   age income group  
#>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>  
#>  1     1    10     35 case   
#>  2     2    20     72 case   
#>  3     3    44     11 case   
#>  4     4    11     35 case   
#>  5   111    12     37 control
#>  6   222    11     36 control
#>  7   333     8     33 control
#>  8   555    11     34 control
#>  9   777    21     70 control
#> 10  1000    18     70 control
```

Check results for a different seed

```
set.seed(234)
for(i in seq_len(nrow(case))){
  x <- which(between(control$age, case$age[i] -2, case$age[i] +2) & 
               between(control$income, case$income[i] -2, case$income[i] + 2) & 
               !control$FILTER)
  control$FILTER[sample(x, min(2, length(x)))] <- TRUE
}
control

bind_rows(case, control) %>% filter(FILTER | is.na(FILTER)) %>% select(-FILTER)

# A tibble: 10 x 4
      id   age income group  
   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>  
 1     1    10     35 case   
 2     2    20     72 case   
 3     3    44     11 case   
 4     4    11     35 case   
 5   111    12     37 control
 6   222    11     36 control
 7   333     8     33 control
 8   555    11     34 control
 9   777    21     70 control
10  1000    18     70 control
```

---

`dat` modified before proceeding for id 3

- split the data into two groups `case` and `control` using baseR's `split
- save two as separate dfs using `list2env`
- using `purrr::map_df` you can take sample 2 rows for each case

  - once for `age`
  - and once for `income`
- finally sample 2 rows again from each of these results
- `bind_rows` again these with `case` also

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat = structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999, 1000), 
                     age = c(10, 20, 44, 12, 11, 8, 12, 11, 22, 21, 18, 21, 18), 
                     income = c(35, 72, 11, 37, 36, 33, 70, 34, 74, 70, 44, 76, 70), 
                     group = c("case", "case", "case", "control", "control", "control", 
                               "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
                               "control", "control")),
                row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

dat
#> # A tibble: 13 x 4
#>       id   age income group  
#>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>  
#>  1     1    10     35 case   
#>  2     2    20     72 case   
#>  3     3    44     11 case   
#>  4   111    12     37 control
#>  5   222    11     36 control
#>  6   333     8     33 control
#>  7   444    12     70 control
#>  8   555    11     34 control
#>  9   666    22     74 control
#> 10   777    21     70 control
#> 11   888    18     44 control
#> 12   999    21     76 control
#> 13  1000    18     70 control

dat %>%
  split(.$group) %>%
  list2env(envir = .GlobalEnv)
#> <environment: R_GlobalEnv>

set.seed(123)
bind_rows(case, map_dfr(case$age, ~ control %>% filter(between(age, .x -2, .x +2) ) %>%
       sample_n(min(n(),2))) %>% sample_n(min(n(),2)),
       map_dfr(case$income, ~ control %>% filter(between(income, .x -2, .x +2)) %>%
                 sample_n(min(n(),2))) %>% sample_n(min(n(),2)))
#> # A tibble: 7 x 4
#>      id   age income group  
#>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>  
#> 1     1    10     35 case   
#> 2     2    20     72 case   
#> 3     3    44     11 case   
#> 4   222    11     36 control
#> 5   777    21     70 control
#> 6   111    12     37 control
#> 7   333     8     33 control
```

---

the below code will also do the same without saving individual dfs

```
dat %>%
  split(.$group) %>%
  {bind_rows(.$case, 
             map_dfr(.$case$age, \(.x) .$control %>% filter(between(age, .x -2, .x +2) ) %>%
                       sample_n(min(n(),2))) %>% sample_n(min(n(),2)),
             map_dfr(.$case$income, \(.x) .$control %>% filter(between(income, .x -2, .x +2)) %>%
                       sample_n(min(n(),2))) %>% sample_n(min(n(),2)))}
```

Comment: Dear @ AnilGoyal , sorry to bother you again. I have another problem. How do I generate a new variable that indicates the control that each case matches? For example, `Control1` and `Control2` matched by `Case1` are encoded as `group 1`, and `Control1` and `Control2` matched by `Case2` are encoded as `group 2`. I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: @zhiweili, please post the link of question or if not posted as separate question already, please do so.

Comment: the new question have posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71402703/how-to-obtain-the-specific-grouping-of-cases-and-controls-in-r

Answer (score 3):

Separate case and control in different dataframes. For each row in `case_data` find the matching rows in `control_data` and select 2 random rows from it.

Using `map_df` we can combine everything in one dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

case_data <- dat %>% filter(group == 'case')
control_data <- dat %>% filter(group == 'control')

case_data %>%
  group_split(row_number(), .keep = FALSE) %>%
  map_df(~bind_rows(.x, control_data %>% 
                    filter(between(age, .x$age - 2, .x$age + 2), 
                           between(income, .x$income - 2, .x$income + 2)) %>%
        slice_sample(n = 2)))

#     id   age income group  
#  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>  
#1     1    10     35 case   
#2   333     8     33 control
#3   111    12     37 control
#4     2    20     72 case   
#5   666    22     74 control
#6   777    21     70 control
```

Comment: In my real situation, the `control` choices overlap, so I've updated the example.

Answer (score 3):

You could also the following solution. I wrapped `map2` function inside curly braces so that I could choose what variables I would like to use for `.x` and `.y`, otherwise `%>%` would've replace the whole data set as the first argument:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dat %>%
  filter(group == "case") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  {map2(.$age, .$income, ~ dat %>% 
          filter(group == "control" & age >= .x - 2 & age <= .x + 2 & 
                   income >= .y - 2 & income <= .y + 2))} %>%
  map_dfr(~ .x %>% 
            slice_sample(n = 2)) %>%
  bind_rows(dat %>% 
              filter(group == "case")) %>%
  arrange(id)

# A tibble: 7 x 4
     id   age income group  
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>  
1     1    10     35 case   
2     2    20     72 case   
3     3    44     11 case   
4   222    11     36 control
5   333     8     33 control
6   777    21     70 control
7  1000    18     70 control
```

Comment: In my real situation, the `control` choices overlap, so I've updated the example.