# How to obtain the specific grouping of cases and controls in r

Tags: r

I want to match 2 `controls` for every `case` with two conditions:

1. the `age` difference should between ±2;
2. the `income` difference should between ±2.

If there are more than 2 `controls` for a `case`, I just need to select 2 `controls` randomly. And then, how do I generate a new variable that indicates the control that each `case` matches? For example, `Control1` and `Control2` matched by `Case1` are encoded as `group 1`, and `Control1` and `Control2` matched by `Case2` are encoded as group 2.

### DATA

```
dat = structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 
                     777, 888, 999, 1000), 
              age = c(10, 20, 44, 11, 12, 11, 8, 12,  11, 22, 21, 18, 21, 18), 
              income = c(35, 72, 11, 35, 37, 36, 33,  70, 34, 74, 70, 44, 76, 70), 
              group = c("case", "case", "case", "case", "control", "control", 
                        "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
                        "control", "control", "control")), 
         row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

### EXPECTED OUTPUT

| id | age | income | group | index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 35 | case | 1 |
| 2 | 20 | 72 | case | 2 |
| 3 | 44 | 11 | case | 3 |
| 4 | 11 | 35 | case | 4 |
| 111 | 12 | 37 | control | 1 |
| 222 | 11 | 36 | control | 1 |
| 333 | 8 | 33 | control | 4 |
| 555 | 11 | 34 | control | 4 |
| 777 | 21 | 70 | control | 2 |
| 1000 | 18 | 70 | control | 2 |

This is similar to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68141082/matching-controls-to-cases-using-multiple-conditions-in-r/68141367?noredirect=1#comment126200426_68141367), but I want the output to have an extra variable called `index` to indicate the specific controls for case matching. If a `case` and a `control` have the same `index`, it means that specific controls is matched with that case.

The question is how can I create the `index`, preferably with an approach based on the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68141082/matching-controls-to-cases-using-multiple-conditions-in-r/68141367?noredirect=1#comment126200426_68141367).

Comment: Please double check your expected output, `id = 3` should not have any matched controls according to your matching criteria

Comment: Thanks @ZhiqiangWang, I have update the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is based on the accepted answer to your previous post by @AnilGoyal:

```
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)
dat %>% mutate(index=0) %>% 
  split(.$group) %>%
  list2env(envir = .GlobalEnv)

set.seed(12345)
for(i in seq_len(nrow(case))){
  x <- which(between(control$age, case$age[i] -2, case$age[i] +2) & 
               between(control$income, case$income[i] -2, case$income[i] + 2) & 
               control$index==0)
 control$index[sample(x, min(2, length(x)))] <- i
 case$index[i] <-i 
}

matched <- case %>% rbind(control) %>% filter(index >0)
matched
```

Please note: You have more than 2 controls meeting the criteria for some cases, 2 controls are randomly selected.

```
> matched 
# A tibble: 10 × 5
      id   age income group   index
   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
 1     1    10     35 case        1
 2     2    20     72 case        2
 3     3    44     11 case        3
 4     4    11     35 case        4
 5   111    12     37 control     4
 6   222    11     36 control     1
 7   333     8     33 control     1
 8   555    11     34 control     4
 9   777    21     70 control     2
10  1000    18     70 control     2
```