# R: How to case-control match by age (1:10)

Tags: r

I am new to R and I am struggling to find a code to age-match 10 controls per case.
All the cases and controls are in one data frame and are assigned 'Case' or 'Control' in a 'Group' column.
I want to make a new data frame with age-matched cases and controls that are +/- 2years of the age of the cases. My dataframe has 112 cases and 4910 controls which should be enough.
This is a small proportion of my dataframe, please let me know if the sample data is too small:

```
structure(list(Sex = c("F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", 
"F", "M", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", 
"F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", 
"M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", 
"M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", 
"F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", 
"M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", 
"M", "F"), mcv = c(89, 90, 86, 87, 90, 88, 85, 90, 92, 89, 87, 
95, 92, 94, 89, 87, 93, 90, 96, 94, 88, 101, 83, 97, 79, 91, 
92, 89, 90, 93, 88, 94, 92, 89, 97, 98, 80, 92, 87, 95, 85, 91, 
89, 89, 94, 77, 92, 92, 82, 92, 85, 105, 96, 102, 89, 87, 87, 
95, 93, 88, 93, 82, 88, 86, 87, 88, 89, 89, 91, 90, 90, 85, 95, 
88, 91, 88, 87, 92, 91, 92, 92, 80, 80, 96, 85, 90, 88, 89, 86, 
91, 91, 76, 94, 86, 94, 84, 88, 92, 101, 91, 93, 98, 98, 91, 
86, 84, 91, 90, 88, 88, 83, 91, NA, 101), Age = c(52, 63, 72, 
52, 66, 59, 51, 63, 68, 53, 64, 70, 70, 78, 59, 55, 54, 54, 83, 
61, 51, 72, 57, 67, 72, 52, 55, 52, 95, 79, 60, 61, 73, 69, 65, 
55, 53, 77, 79, 54, 64, 54, 65, 71, 63, 52, 54, 63, 69, 70, 56, 
80, 54, 67, 59, 71, 56, 73, 53, 61, 71, 73, 74, 63, 82, 60, 52, 
65, 75, 66, 74, 71, 58, 52, 53, 55, 91, 73, 62, 51, 74, 73, 64, 
60, 58, 63, 63, 59, 72, 52, 85, 51, 61, 56, 60, 64, 73, 78, 57, 
52, 62, 64, 70, 62, 58, 69, 84, 72, 71, 63, 73, 63.3, 62.3, 59.56
), Group = c("Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Case", "Case", "Case"
)), row.names = c(NA, -114L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I have tried codes from other questions but they don't work:

[Matching controls to cases using multiple conditions in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68141082/matching-controls-to-cases-using-multiple-conditions-in-r)

```
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)

dat %>%
  split(.$group) %>%
  list2env(envir = .GlobalEnv)

control$FILTER <- FALSE
control

set.seed(123)

for(i in seq_len(nrow(case))){
  x <- which(between(control$age, case$age[i] -2, case$age[i] +2) & 
               !control$FILTER)
  control$FILTER[sample(x, min(10, length(x)))] <- TRUE
}

control

bind_rows(case, control) %>% filter(FILTER | is.na(FILTER)) %>% select(-FILTER)
```

The product of this code above had 30 controls missing.

```
case_data <- dat %>% filter(group == 'case')
control_data <- dat %>% filter(group == 'control')

case_data %>%
  group_split(row_number(), .keep = FALSE) %>%
  map_df(~bind_rows(.x, control_data %>% 
                    filter(between(age, .x$age - 2, .x$age + 2)) %>%
        slice_sample(n = 10)))
```

The product of this code above was an error:

```
Error in `slice_sample()`:
! Problem while computing indices.
Caused by error in `sample.int()`:
! invalid first argument
```

My expected outcome is:

| mcv | Age | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 62 | Case |
| 99 | 61 | Control |
| 98 | 63 | Control |
| 101 | 60 | Control |
| 87 | 64 | Control |
| 98 | 62 | Control |
| 95 | 62 | Control |
| 99 | 63 | Control |
| 97 | 60 | Control |
| 90 | 63 | Control |
| 102 | 64 | Control |
| 98 | 70 | Case |
| 90 | 69 | Control |
| 98 | 70 | Control |
| 99 | 71 | Control |
| 100 | 71 | Control |
| 98 | 72 | Control |
| 96 | 68 | Control |
| 109 | 68 | Control |
| 98 | 69 | Control |
| 90 | 70 | Control |
| 100 | 70 | Control |

So on...

Does anyone know another code or know why these don't work? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi - Welcome to SO! In order to better help can you provide a minimal working example of your data? You can use the dput() function in R to get started. Currently, we do not know what the `dat` object is so are unable to help. Providing a data example will yield a higher probability of your question being answered promptly.  Example of dput: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49994249/example-of-using-dput. Also a link on reproducible examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm assuming the data is the sample in the linked question. I can tell you that when you remove `slice_sample()` you will see why you get that error. If there aren't 10 observations within 2 years it will just error out. The third case has no controls associated within 2 years, for example. (The age is 44.) Additionally, there is very little sample data to see what other issues could arise here.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the comments. I edited the original post, please let me know if the data example is wrong.